# Pig - Performing aggregation on inner join results

Tags: apache-pig

I have performed an inner join on two tables. However, I am unable to perform the summation on one of the cloumns:

Queries performed:

```
sample1 = load '/user/tweets/samples.csv' using PigStorage AS (line:chararray);
words = FOREACH sample1 GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(LOWER(TRIM(line)),'[\\p{Punct},\\p{Cntrl}]',''))) AS word
newinnerjoin = join words by word, wordlexion by lexword;
```

Below is the output of the table: newinnerjoin

```
(important,important,2)
(irritated,irritated,-3)
(promoting,promoting,1)
(promoting,promoting,1)
(appreciate,appreciate,2)
(confidence,confidence,2)
```

I want to perform the aggregation on column 3 of the inner join results.
So, I would like the sum to be calculated as 2 + -3 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 5
IS there a way i can do without storing the inner join results in csv file ?
Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add the below 3 lines of code and let me know the result?.

```
A = GROUP newinnerjoin  ALL;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE SUM(newinnerjoin.$2);
DUMP B;
```